# XML autoformat in Visual Studio Code

Tags: xml, format, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code automatically format the content of XML tags?

I want to have an indent when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or even when closing a tag:

Not as

[image: The wrong way]

but this way:

[image: The right way]

Comment: Have you searched the extensions? There are plenty of XML related extensions out there, find one that works for you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to indent the line?

Comment: Yes, i've searched, but it seems none of them do this.
@ifconfig, I mean it will make an empty line between strart and end tags and this line will have an indent (tab).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension, from Red Hat, supports auto-indentation on enter, among many useful other features (like validation, code completion, autoclose tag...):

[image: auto-indent-on-enter]